# Sandbox metadata .zip file is size exceed the size limit in Intellij

Tags: metadata, sandbox, intellij

I'm trying to load the metadata of a sandbox org into Intellij using illuminated cloud but the operation took too much time and fail at the end, and the following error message is displayed :

[image]

Comment: You are trying to retrieve to much metadata at once. You will have to remove some metadata members in order to stay within the Salesforce limit (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_metadata.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce metadata API has two limits:

1. max number of metadata components in a retrieve or deploy - 10K for unmanaged and 12.5K for managed.
2. max file size limit.

You are hitting this second limit. Easiest thing to do is to reduce the number of profiles in your retrieve or even better drop Documents metadata type if you are fetching it.

Answer (score 1):

Latest **Metadata Limits** can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_metadata.htm).

> File Count

- **10,000** for both **Change** **Sets** and **Deploy**()
  or **Retrieve**() using ANT
- **30,000** for **AppExchange** packages for **apiVersion** **47.0** and above.

> File Size

- Uncompressed unzipped folder ~ **400MB***
- After Compression ~ **39MB**
- After base64Encoding ~ **50MB** [*Addition due to encoding*]

** *The size of the unzipped folder can vary based on the compression ratio and contents present. The enforcement of file size is because the final file must be less than **50MB** due to SOAP API Limit.*